# Problem with Access-Control-Allow-Origin on Wordpress Multisite

Tags: .htaccess, multisite, cross-origin-resource-policy

I'm running a Wordpress Multisite. The first/main site is using the domain "mainsite.com" while the subsites severall different domains from "subsite.mainsite.com" to "subsite.com" or "subsite.differentsite.com".
I've got some cross-origins error and wanted to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" but for other reasons I would like to only do this on the main site.

I tried to do it in PHP:

```
<?php if ($blog_id = 1) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
} ?>
```

But that failes and no Access-Control-Allow-Origin was set. Next I tried to do this in the .htaccess:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'mainsite.com'">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</If>
```

That DOES set it but it also seems to be active for "subsite.com". Could anybody give me a pointer what I am doing wrong? These configurations are not my strong suit and any help would be great!

EDIT: I'm trying to use a form from a subsite on my main site using this code:

```
switch_to_blog($blogid);
Ninja_Forms()->display($formtoshow);
restore_current_blog();
```

I get the error when I'm trying to send the form:

```
CORS-Kopfzeile 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' fehlt). Statuscode: 200.
```

Comment: _"I tried to do it in PHP [...] But that failes and no Access-Control-Allow-Origin was set."_ - and the errors you are getting, they _are_ for a resource handled by PHP in the first place? _"Next I tried to do this in the .htaccess:"_ - not sure what could be wrong with that, I don't see how this could trigger if the requested host name was _not_ `mainsite.com` - unless your setup involves some weird proxying of requests somehow?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added the problematic PHP code in the question above since that seems to be easier. Unfortunately I can't rule ou weird proxying since I didnt develop the site from the ground up. Was honestly hoping that I just made a syntax mistake or something.

Comment: _"I'm trying to use a form from a subsite on my main site"_ - so that presumably involves AJAX for the submission then, and that's what's giving your CORS errors? Can you please be explicitly clear about the "from" and "to" here? Right now, it sounds you are showing the form _on_ your main site, but the AJAX request goes _to_ the subsite? Then that subsite would have to respond with the header, not your main site.

Comment: Sorry! There is a form (NinjaForm) on subsite.com. I want to use that form on mainsite.com with the code written in the question (switch_to_blog...). This works fine but as soon as I click the send button, I get a CORS error. If I set Allow-Origin in an if-statement in the .htaccess (which is the same for subsite.com and mainsite.com since it's a multisite) it works BUT the setting seems to be active also for subsite.com.
The PHP version was in header.php which is also the same for all sites (multisite...) but it should only work for mainsite.com (or blog_id=1) but that did not seem to work.

Comment: So you got it the wrong way around then. mainsite is making the request _to_ subsite, so subsite needs to respond with the header, not mainsite. But with your PHP code you appear to have implemented the exact opposite (blog id 1 _is_ your mainsite, I assume?)

Comment: And that `if ($blog_id = 1)` is actually an _assignment_ - comparison uses `==` (or `===` for an additional type match check at the same time.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually implemented it in the .htaccess as before but with != instead of == and it seems to work perfectly. I just understood that completly wrong.
If anything changes with that I would again try the PHP solutions but as I said, seems to work fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it the wrong way around and

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'mainsite.com'">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</If>
```

did the trick since the correct header as to come from the subsite.

Comment: But now this header will be sent for _all_ subsites - and since you were so insistent on not having it sent for main- and subsite when you asked the question, I am wondering if that is what you actually want now? Or if this should not rather be `== 'subsite.com'`

Comment: I will experiment further but I think my reasoning for not having it has solved itself. When I tried my old, wrong solution I sometimes got the error message on subhside.com for a different usecase that there were multiple Access-Control in place which is not allowed. This is no longer the case and it works on both sides. I will howerver try to search a solution which does not open everything. Thanks four your help.